# How do I track AJAX sections in Magento Onepage with Google Analytics Async

Tags: ajax, magento, asynchronous, google-analytics

I have a magento store and I am trying to track the progress of users at the checkout process.

I have the Onepage checkout enabled - which does some ajax stuff to essentially load 6 different steps in an accordion format. I would like to track each step with Google Analytics so i know whats putting the users off.. I found this link (http://magentoexpert.co.uk/2009/03/08/tracking-one-page-checkout-abandonment-with-google-analytics-properly/) to do so with Google Analytics - but it uses the old GA code. I am using the Async code which uses the gaq push.

So here is the code they recommend to use.

```
 gotoSection: function(section)
    {
        try {
            pageTracker._trackPageview('/checkout/' + section + '/');
        } catch(err) {}

        section = $('opc-'+section);
        section.addClassName('allow');
        this.accordion.openSection(section);
    },
```

To update this to the Asynchronous version, would i use:

```
 gotoSection: function(section)
    {
        try {
            _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/checkout/', + section + '/']);
        } catch(err) {}

        section = $('opc-'+section);
        section.addClassName('allow');
        this.accordion.openSection(section);
    },
```

Do i need the catch(err) ? What would be the full code - this doesn't seem to work for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the Fooman GoogleAnalyticsPlus extension on [MagentoConnect](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/FOOMAN/extension/171/fooman-google-analytics-plus) will do what you need. YMMV.

Comment: Great - thanks for the heads up, I will look into that, but whilst this question is on here, how would i finish the above code example?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who comes here, the above code does not work because it needs to be /checkout/onepage/ instead of just /checkout/

View correct example here: http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/onepage-checkout-abandonment-google-analytics/

Comment: This implementation works very well. Put everything in place, let it go for a few days. If it doesn't appear to work correctly, go to each step and blank the url entry. When you go to reenter it, Google may suggest a link ending in index.php. Select the appropriate one for each step, save and then go check your funnel visualization. Google will now find the seat of its pants and start showing extraneous entries and dropout numbers. People exiting in the Shipping Method are finding your freight charges are too high, etc. PS: The Goal URL will need to be changed if the step URLs need it.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I have functioning, note the added function at the bottom. I wanted to track failed submission button action, this is added to the onclick and generates its own independent event tracking adding the **Submit Order** step just previous to the success goal in the chain:

```
<!-- Google Funnel Stats -->
<script type="text/javascript">
Checkout.prototype.gotoSection = function(section) {

    try {
        // Google Analytics non-asynch code
        // pageTracker._trackPageview('/checkout/onepage/'+section+'/');

        // Google Analytics asynchronus code
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/checkout/onepage/'+section+'/']);

    } catch(err) { }

    section = $('opc-'+section);
    section.addClassName('allow');
    this.accordion.openSection(section);
}

function gaqSubmitOrder() {

    try {
        // Google Analytics non-asynch code
        // pageTracker._trackPageview('/checkout/onepage/'+section+'/');

        // Google Analytics asynchronus code
        _gaq.push(['_trackPageview', '/checkout/onepage/submitorder/']);

    } catch(err) { }

}
</script>
```